# Persisting a single, static, large Postgres database beyond removal of the db cluster?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume, postgresql-10, tablespace

I have an application which, for local development, has multiple Docker containers (organized under Docker Compose). One of those containers is a Postgres 10 instance, based on the official `postgres:10` image. That instance has its data directory mounted as a Docker volume, which persists data across container runs. All fine so far.

As part of testing the creation and initialization of the postgres cluster, it is frequently the case that I need to remove the Docker volume that holds the data. (The official postgres image runs cluster init if-and-only-if the data directory is found to be empty at container start.) This is also fine.

However! I now have a situation where in order to test and use a third party Postgres extension, I need to load around 6GB of (entirely static) geocoding lookup data into a database on the cluster, from Postgres backup dump files. It's certainly possible to load the data from a local mount point at container start, and the resulting (very large) tables would persist across container restarts in the volume that holds the entire cluster.

Unfortunately, they won't survive the removal of the docker volume which, again, needs to happen with some frequency. **I am looking for a way to speed up or avoid the rebuilding of the single database which holds the geocoding data.**

Approaches I have been or currently am considering:

1. Using a separate Docker volume on the same container to create persistent storage for a separate Postgres tablespace that holds only the geocoder database. This appears to be unworkable because while I can definitely set it up, the official PG docs say that tablespaces and clusters are inextricably linked such that the loss of the rest of the cluster would render the additional tablespace unusable. I would love to be wrong about this, since it seems like the simplest solution.
2. Creating an entirely separate container running Postgres, which mounts a volume to hold a separate cluster containing only the geocoding data. Presumably I would then need to do something kludgy with foreign data wrappers (or some more arcane postgres admin trickery that I don't know of at this point) to make the data seamlessly accessible from the application code.

So, my question: **Does anyone know of a way to persist a single database from a dockerized Postgres cluster, without resorting to a dump and reload strategy?**

Comment: Personally I'd probably make a "postgres + extension" docker image and run that. You can mount a copy of the 6gb data volume for the image and let it get mutated from that point onwards.

Comment: The data doesn't mutate--it's entirely static. All the other parts of the cluster have the potential to change based on what happens during cluster init, but this one large database will be the same no matter what happens then. It's why I'd like to be able to persist just the one database but be able to otherwise destroy the main data directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up then you could convert your database dump to a data directory (import your dump to a clean postgres container, stop it and create a tarball of the data directory, then upload it somewhere). Now when you need to create a new postgres container use use a init script to stop the database, download and unpack your tarball to the data directory and start the database again, this way you skip the whole db restore process.

Note: The data tarball has to match the postgres major version so the container has no problem to start from it.

If you want to speed up things even more then create a custom postgres image with the tarball and init script bundled so everytime it starts then it will wipe the empty cluster and copy your own.

You could even change the entrypoint to use your custom script and load the database data, then call docker-entrypoint.sh so there is no need to delete a possible empty cluster.

This will only work if you are OK with replacing the whole cluster everytime you want to run your tests, else you are stuck with importing the database dump.

Comment: Archiving the data directory isn't going to help, because it'll have all the other parts of the Postgres cluster in it as well. Those are the parts I need to purge so that I can force the container to rebuild the cluster from my initdb.d scripts.

Comment: Yes, my answer assumes that you can prepare a data directory that only have the geocoding data on a database and nothing else, this means converting your database dump beforehand. Postgres doesn't really support importing parts of the tablespace for a single database.